# Language selection page as default page for website

Tags: internationalization

I am updating my website and I am adding multiple languages.

I was wanting to do this by having the website open to the default page were the  user can select there language.

Is this a good way to do this.

Comment: What backend are you using? Is your question ui- or backend-related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking the [Accept-Language HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) on the server and send the content back in that language (if you can), then include a simple language selector in a prominent place such as the upper left corner.

You might want to have a look over here too: [What is a good interface to allow display in multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5061026/479863)

Answer (score 1):

IMO **No** instead you should first show default page (with usual stuff) in English  (As unarguably the most used language) and then provide option to switch Locale (Language) if user want to. You can take Idea from various Multilingual  websites on internet.

Visitors most likely wants to see stuff rather then an option to select language(..personally i hate this design). If visitor feels he is not comfortable with language he will most probably search for such an option on that very page or on Home page.

Later when user has selected his preferred language, you can store it in his cookies and render content in chosen language thereafter.

You can go one step forward and workout the [location of User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country) with his IP address.

*For Example [Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/preview/default.aspx) shows current locale in top-right corner and clicking on it gives you full chart of different languages supported.*

Answer (score 0):

You could do what google does, which is default to the language of the country that the person is connecting from. You can detect this by IP address. There are a number of IP location databases: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software

Comment: Country isn't quite enough. Switzerland has four official languages, Canada has two, Finland has two, South Africa has 11 (!), etc.

Comment: Sure, but if you're trying to maximize user experience, it's still a good default. The alternative (e.g. UPS website) is to ask the user every time they initially open the site. I think this is much worse than just choosing a default which is highly probable to be correct.

Comment: Yeah, country is a reasonable fallback after checking Accept-Language and possibly `navigator.language` (and `navigator.userLanguage`) on the client side. There's also the "German businessman in Tokyo" problem with using country.